# how solve duplicate method error compilation in Talend?

Tags: talend

When i execute my job it gives me a compilation error

> "Duplicate method getIntitule() in type
>   remplir_etablissement_v2.row.Struct"

how can I deal with please thanks !

Comment: two methods with same name.

Comment: so, how can i solve it in talend?

Comment: try to keep unique name of methods.

Answer (score 0):

The getter method are automatically generated according to the schema of the row. In your problem, the main link nammed "row" (not sure of that) may have 2 columns with the same name (it will be a bug as Talend Studio don't allow that).

You should try to localize the bad main link and recreate it, you probably had a bug in your Talend Studio.

Comment: there are columns that have the same names between table when i create a tMAP...i've already change names but still i've the same problem . How can I find this bad main link?

Comment: @Haitam To be clear : having two columns with the same name in 2 different schema is not a problem (e.g. in a tMap the ingoing and outgoing columns can have the same name). You likely have a bug and a row link contains 2 columns with the same name (it happens to me some times).
To find the root of the problem, try to go in the "code" tabs, you will find the compilation errors in the generated code. By looking the code above the compilation error, I think you will be able to locate which row have the duplicated columns.

Comment: ok thanks I will try it. I would mention that in spite of this warning the job execute correctly and gives the output that i need. But I couldn't generate the .bat file because of this warning :(